# wow.js happens on page load and not on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html), and it works fine, except the animations all happen immediately after the page load, and not when they are scrolled to. I followed the docs, but can't figure it out.

There are no JS errors on the page. I included both animate.min.css and wow.js

in the body:

```
<img src="images/philosophy.png" alt="Philosophy" id="philosophy-img" class="icon wow bounceInUp">
```

and in the footer:

```
<script>
    new WOW().init();
</script>
```

So how can use wow.js to get the animations to happen when scrolling to a particular div?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's the solution I found via a [closed Github Issue:](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/33) you can add this to your CSS:

```
.wow {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

WOW will then toggle it to visible when starting the animation.

Comment: this was what worked for me in my situation.  On page load the images would appear briefly, then get hidden when once the page finally loaded.  Thanks

Comment: I noticed I was having this issue as well and it makes the page look amateur'ish from an otherwise fantastic library. Solution above worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Late response however this still may help others.

If WOW.js is still not working after adding the latest version or adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` the problem may be due to a conflict in the scroll (or more specifically the viewport).

In my case, the problem was caused within my CSS when using the following:

`html, body {height:100%; width:100%; overflow:hidden}`

By removing the height and width properly, I was able to solve the problem as Wow.js was then able to notice **when the element came into the viewport** and change the elements visibility.

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue (and solution) with a wrapping <div> elements and max-height property

Comment: Perfect, that helped to find the problem. The overflow-x property was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem.
was using
`class="wow bounceInUp"`

**Then I tried**
`class="wow bounceInUp animated"`

And it worked

EDIT: in the end, it didn't work. It worked at first but then stopped. Even bigger mystery :S

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same problem and I just figured it out. The issue was that the `<script>` in the footer is incomplete, or at least it didn't work to me.

Whoever's got this problem give a try to this code instead, just before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
wow = new WOW( {
    boxClass:     'wow',
    animateClass: 'animated',
    offset:       100
    }
);

wow.init();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today, because I was using a fixed navigation bar width a height of 160px the content was loaded before I could see it.

I solved it by adding an offset in the WOW initialization :

```
new WOW({offset: 160 }).init()
```

Hope it could help.

Answer (score 1):

For bouncing on the answer proposed by DesignofKA, I had the same issue due to fixed height property in a wrapping div.

I simply init wow during window.onload event to solve the wow problem.

My code is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var wow = new WOW({
        boxClass: 'wow',
        animateClass: 'animated',
        offset: 0,
        mobile: true,
        live: true
    });
    wow.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if I knew the browser you are using and the WOW.js version.

Also, please give the [latest version](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/releases) a try, we've done some changes to address issues with Firefox which might fix your problem too. Particularly, in [0.1.9](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/releases/tag/0.1.9).

If your problem persists, please [report the bug](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues), and try to provide an example page and tell us which browser are you using.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had just forgotten to add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The answer here helped - 
[wow.js only works when scrolling up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580552/wow-js-only-works-when-scrolling-up)

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with @DesignofKA post. For me it conflicted wit this line of code:

```
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Hopefully this was helpful.