# wow.js only works when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have implemented wow.js into my webpage, but for some reason it only animates elements when scrolling up the page, opposed to down the page.

The code I'm using is

```
<script src="wow.js"></script>
<script>
 new WOW().init();
</script>
```

And using

```
<div class='circle wow bounceInLeft'></div>
```

for elements I want to animate in when scrolling down.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle? Or any online link?

Comment: Same problem here, anyone managed to solved it?

Comment: Here is my online link with the same problem: http://veduo.nl/ 
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on a webpage I started working locally on my computer for tests purposes only. Because of that, I'd completely ignored best practices at all and forgot to include a Doctype declaration.

**So I just added a**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the beginning of my page, and the plugin worked properly. Down the page as it should be.

This at least might be the solution for @krunsolo in the comments, in which there is no Doctype declaration inside the link he provided. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Hi @cfviotty, actually, the doctype is declared. So this does not solve it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented wow.js into my webpage, but for some reason it only animates elements when scrolling up the page, opposed to down the page.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this?