# How do I change the style property of items when are in viewport on scrollable section?

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter

I'm on CodeIgniter with Bootstrap and I have a problem with [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html), only items in viewport are shown instead on scroll down all items are there but the visibility is equal to hidden and doesn't change it.

The problem is that I'm on a scrollable section.

***UPDATE***

I found a workaround [here](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/65#issuecomment-87470093), so for the purpose I used the `wow.js` for the animation and the `isInViewport.min.js`for the triggering.

My `head`:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">            </script>
  <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>      
</head>
```

My `template`:

```
        <section  id="scrollab" class="scrollable  w-f-md" style="position:fixed; z-index:1">  
                  <div id="target"  style="height:100%;">                  
                    <?php getPage($page); ?>
                  </div> <!-- /target -->
        </section>
```

My `view`: (it's the page target)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<script src="isInViewport.min.js"></script>
<div class="row row-sm padder-lg ">
    <?php
    foreach ($top->feed->entry as $key => $value) 
    {
        $value->title->label = str_ireplace( "- ".$value->artist->label, "",  $value->title->label);
        if($key >= $this->config->item("items_top"))
            continue;
        $image = $value->image[2]->label;
        if($image == '')
            $image = base_url()."assets/images/no-cover.png";
        $image = str_ireplace("170x170", "200x200", $image);
    ?>      
    <div class="wow bounceInUp col-sm-4" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <div class="item " >
            <div class="pos-rlt ">
                <figure class="effect-main-2">
                    <img class="img-full" src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/>                     
                    <figcaption>
                        <div style="overflow:hidden;"></div>
                        <div class="item-overlay opacity">
                            <span class="text-center">
                                <i class="icon-control-play"></i>    
                            </span>                
                        </div>                       
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      

    <script>
       new WOW().init();
    </script>
```

And then, on the same view as suggested, I added this script:

```
    <script>
      var scrollable = $('#scrollab');
          scrollable.on('scroll.wow', function(){
          scrollable.find('.wow:not(.animated):in-viewport').removeAttr('style').addClass('animated');
        }));
    </script>

</div>
```

Now everything works fine, thanks to you all.

Comment: Did you check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531064/wow-js-happens-on-page-load-and-not-on-scroll)?

Comment: @anpsmn Hi, yes I saw and try almost everything but nothing has changed

Comment: Difficult to say until there is a link to the actual page or a fiddle that reproduces it. Try to remove the class `animated` from the div and check. I guess wow.js adds the `animated` class when you scroll.

Comment: @anpsmn that class is in the only overlay...I just added the link to my website

Comment: Reading this [issue](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/61) I guess it could be that a script is not letting wow's scroll handler to be called. You can try removing a plugin that uses scroll like the custom scrollbar on the site. Best is to create a new issue there on [their](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues) page.

Comment: @anpsmn thanks to your suggest, I spoke with the maker, and found a possible solution here [link](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/65#issuecomment-87470093) But I'm not able to workaround, just try it but it's using a jQuery and I have not enough knoledge

Comment: I try it out (http://jsfiddle.net/tfLp17oz/) and everything seems to be working fine. To help you diagnose where the problem is try some of the following:
1) make sure there are no JS error when page is loaded, and when the section is scrolled
2) make sure that the last script (with the scrollabe fix) is executed after WOW.init.
3) Add "console.log('test');" after the "scrollable.find" 
4) Remove the "overflow: scroll" for #scrollab and make sure the animations work. 
This way we can get closer to finding the problem.

Comment: @ChavdarSlavov Thanks for the Fiddle! I don't know what it's wrong, I just updated my question, the scrollable section is in my template, instead my items to display are on a page view

Comment: your error indicates the inviewport js is not loaded

Comment: In my jsfiddle example i use this plugin http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport it works fine, it should fix your issue.

Comment: @ChavdarSlavov I love you guys! Finally I found out the problem...I don't know why but in my particular case I needed to add the `isInViewport.min.js` directly in the view (add it in the header didn't work)

Comment: Yep, the simplest errors are harder to find. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i was able to reproduce and solve your issue. Basically `:in-viewport` not is included in jquery pseudo selectors. So you need a plugin like http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport for it to be able to work properly. Also make sure this plugin is loaded in your page.

Here is a working example for the `:in-viewport` http://jsfiddle.net/tfLp17oz/