# wow.js, works in Vue component but visibility:hidden; is not being overwritten in native html

Tags: vue.js, wow.js

Just paid for a commercial licence and trying to follow the docs but can't get the animation to work

I am using Laravel 5.4 and Vue 2

```
<head> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/animate.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
     @yield('content')
  </div>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script> // vue file
  <script src="/js/wow.js"></script> 
  <script>
    var wow = new WOW();
    wow.init();
    console.log(wow); // works fine 
  </script>
</body>

// content 
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
   <div class="wow slideInLeft"> // not working 
      <p>Test</p> // not working when applied here either
   </div>
@stop
```

Where am I going wrong?

update, wow is being applied to my Vue components but not native html tags.

it seems that style="visibility: hidden;" is not being overwritten.

```
// Vue component with working wow animation
// this component is on the same page where I want to apply wow to native html 
    <template name="test">
      <p class="wow bounceIn>Test</p> // works
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wow.js happens on page load and not on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531064/wow-js-happens-on-page-load-and-not-on-scroll)

I was applying height and width constraints with CSS 
Removing these made it work