# How can I use WOW.JS properly?

Tags: javascript, css, wow.js

I did all what they say on their "how to use" section. added its JS code (I opted to use a CDN) and the example (class="wow bounce"). but it doesn't do anything. browsing, I found a solution (add .wow {visibility: hidden} from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531064/wow-js-happens-on-page-load-and-not-on-scroll)). okay, there is a solution, but it isn't in the wow.js page or github readme. how can I use it properly stackoverflowlessly?

here is my wow.js-related code:

```
<body>
...
<div class="wow bounce">...</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.boomcdn.com/libs/wow-js/1.3.0/wow.js">
</script>
<script>new WOW().init();</script>
</body>
```

Comment: have you imported "animate.css" ?

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: Yup, I have animation.css working fine. And there are no errors, the classes aren’t just loaded xs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stumped me too.  The answer depends on whether you are using animate.css version 4 or newer.

If you're using the latest from https://animate.style/, you'll need to make some changes.

```
new WOW().init();
```

becomes

```
new WOW({animateClass: 'animate__animated'}).init();
```

and when attaching an animation class to a DOM element, the class name should now be prefixed by `animate__`.  Instead of something like `<img class="wow fadeInUp">` you would have `<img class="wow animate__fadeInUp">`.